# InvalidConfigurationException invalid success handler Symfony

Tags: symfony, configuration, exception

I want to specify change password success handler in my configuration file so that it will route to path which I've specified

I am doing this in my security.yml file under `security.firewalls.main`

```
change_password:
    success_handler: redirect.after.change_password
```

where `redirect.after.change_password` is my service class in which I've specify it where to route.

it shows error :

> Unrecognized option "change_password" under "security.firewalls.main"

where and how should it be mentioned so that it'll work properly.

Thanking in an anticipation

Comment: Where did you find information that you should do such configuration? Also why do you want to configure section of security bundle to do something that it's not related with?

Comment: as we can route aur login page to different routes sepecified by us on basis of role assigned to user, and also we can specify aur login success handler than why not change password's success handler ?

Comment: Because logging in is handled by Symfony Security Component, while changing password is not. That's why. How do you implement changing password? Please provide the code. You probably can simply do the redirect in your controller.

Comment: yes i am just redirecting in that class. which i've made service

Comment: class PasswordResettingListener implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;
    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS => 'onPasswordResettingSuccess',
        ];
    }
    public function onPasswordResettingSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('vehicle_management_user_page');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}

Comment: Well it seems you utilize `FOSUserBundle`, so you have to understand that this is separate thing from Security Component. You can't configure FOSUserBundle undet framework's config section. Anyway your listener seems to be ok. I'm confused about what is the problem now since you make a redirect in this listener.